# rails has many complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I have multiple `has_many` associations in different models.

I am trying to get all those `posts` where `asset_urls` are empty.

```
class Post
 has_many :assets
 ...
end

class Asset
 has_many :asset_urls
 ...
end

class AssetUrl
 ...
end
```

What is the best and most optimized way to achieve those `posts` where `asset_urls` are nil/empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do something like
Post.includes(:assets).where.missing(:asset_urls)